# How do I go to a step definition from a feature file in a protractor-cucumber framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, specflow

In c# spec flow if we click F12 on a DSL or if we right click and select "Go to step definition" on any DSL in feature file, it takes automatically to the binding method present in step def file. We use [Binding]
attribute in the step def .cs file

I have a feature file and a step definition file in .js in my protractor cucumber framework

Do we have similar way in protractor cucumber framework wherein I can navigate from my feature file to step def file by just a click or shortcut .

During any maintenance of test cases it takes long time to search the binded method. Kindly help on it.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding step definitions without an IDE's assistance, maybe you should make your folder structure better?

Comment: i am using Visual Studio code.It does not provide any option in right click menu to select "Go to Step Definition" as in Visual Studio.Do we have anything similar to spec flow in VS code?

Comment: So this is about IDE's? From what I know, no IDE's currently support CucumberJS 2.x syntax, WebStorm (Jetbrains) had amazing support for CucumberJS 1.x syntax, I'm not sure about VS - but I would be surprised if they had support for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Cucumber Full Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete) visual studio code plugin which claims it has this functionality